# TensorFlow: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, I have set up a neural network as follows:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
th = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
th_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


rlu_1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=tf.reshape([x,x_,th,th_],[1,4]),num_outputs=10)

# 4 state features: x, x_, th, th_
rlu_1.weights_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[4],minval=-1,maxval=1) # is this 4 or 10?
rlu_1.biases_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[1],minval=-1,maxval=1)
rlu_2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=rlu_1,num_outputs=10) # hope that makes a copy
rlu_2.weights_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[10],minval=-1,maxval=1)
rlu_2.biases_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[1],minval=-1,maxval=1)
Qvals = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=rlu_2,num_outputs=2)
Qvals.weights_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[10],minval=-1,maxval=1)
Qvals.biases_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[1],minval=-1,maxval=1)
Qvals.activation_fn = tf.identity


xt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
tht = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
th_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# I build a separate copy of the network here, using [xt,x_t,tht and th_t] as inputs
```

I use the following code to run a session:

```
observation = env.reset()
observation = [float(i) for i in observation]
prev_observation = observation
#print(observation)
reward = 1.0
tfreward = tf.constant(reward, dtype=tf.float32)

train_,nextAction = sess.run(train,tf.argmax(Qvals,0),
                              {x:prev_observation[0],x_:prev_observation[1],
                              th:prev_observation[2],th_:prev_observation[3],   
                              xt:observation[0],x_t:observation[1],
                              tht:observation[2],th_t:observation[3]})
```

The trouble is that I'm getting the following error at the final line of the code above:

```
  File "C:/Users/linna_t3vz49n/Documents/CS 486/a4/cartPole.py", line 236, in <module>
    tht:observation[2],th_t:observation[3]})

  File "C:\Users\linna_t3vz49n\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 783, in run
    compat.as_bytes(options.SerializeToString()))

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send list of `[train,tf.argmax(Qvals,0)]` to the `sess.run`

```
train_,nextAction = sess.run([train,tf.argmax(Qvals,0)],
                          {x:prev_observation[0],x_:prev_observation[1],
                          th:prev_observation[2],th_:prev_observation[3],   
                          xt:observation[0],x_t:observation[1],
                          tht:observation[2],th_t:observation[3]})
```